# How do you use Oracle ODP.net ExecuteReader with SP that returns a cursor in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have a procedure that returns a ref cursor. It takes 4 parameters and I am using C#. I have looked for examples all over the net but can't get any of them to work

This is what I have

```
public static int test(int test_id, int progr, int setID, string BFilter)
{
  object cur1 = System.DBNull.Value;
  string spname = "SP.GetValues";

  using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand command = DB.GetStoredProcCommand(spname, test_id, progr, setID, BFilter, cur1))
  {
    using (OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
        //load array
      }
    }
  }

  int t = 1;
  return t;
}
```

I was using a Dataset which worked fine except it was taking 20 secs everytime to get 500 rows and i have to do that 800 times.  I thought using a datareader, loading it into an array then looping over the array would be faster than reading into a dataset.  The SP itself takes 1 sec to return, it spends 19 secs in the fill line.

Comment: @user72226 - If the problem is performance rather than functionality, have you tried fetching from the cursor in, say, SQL*Plus?  Oracle can open a cursor before it even begins executing the query so it is entirely possible that the cursor is opened quickly but that it takes time to actually execute the query when you start fetching the data.

Comment: Tried that and it does it in under a second.  The delay is in filling the dataset on the C# side.  I want to test if a datareader would be faster, but can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Mark William's Blog has a [neat article on using "fetch size" to increase performance](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2007/05/odpnet-tip-ref-cursors-and-fetchsize.html) when using an Oracle Ref Cursor. Very interesting read and may be a good place to start for a sample.

It is a bit older (and I, as an admission, have not touched ODP.NET for a few years), but I doubt ODP.NET has radically changed its spots.

Comment: Interesting tip, however relies on using unsupported hack.  This will be used in production environment which would make any deliberate use of an unsupported feature grounds for termination!

Comment: I will have to see if I can dig up the code I used when I played with ODP and ref cursors last. I would imagine it is still appropriate (although Oracle HAS been known to completely reinvent the wheel with a new release).

Comment: That hack in Mark Williams' blog is no longer required because Rowsize is now an official property of OracleDataReader. Keep in mind that ODP.NET backwardly supports older Oracle Database versions, for example ODP.NET 11.2 supports Oracle 9.2. So no need to stay on a ancient version of ODP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to specify that as an output parameter of type ref. cursor,
Check the following link for more details: [ODP.NET in-out Curors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-jan/o16odpnet-087852.html)